# UIView animation in completion block starts with displacement

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I wrote a simple animation chain with two animations using `UIView.animate`, but the second animation in completion block starts not exactly from where the first animation ens so I have strange displacement to the right. Anyone could help? Maybe I did not fully understand `tranfrorm` property.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
    self.redView.transform = self.redView.transform.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 0)
}) { (_) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.redView.transform = self.redView.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
    })
}
```

My `redView` should be moved to right on 100 and then from the same place became twice as large. But before second animation there is displacement to the right. I have no ideas about why this happens.
Thanks!

**Gif with this issue:**

[image]

Comment: Please add the code of animate method.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya, there is a code for this animation in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's your intention but I'd animate the frame in the first block:

```
let initialFrame = redView.frame
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
    self.redView.frame = initialFrame.offsetBy(dx: 100, dy: 0)
}) { (_) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.redView.transform = self.redView.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
    })
}
```

Comment: Really works. Thanks! But maybe you know what's difference between animation with frames and with transform?